# Appending multiple articles to a single file

Tags: article

I have three tex files with documentclass as article with title, author and different content for each.

How do I combine these files to a single file so that I get continuous page numbers.

Will `\include{}` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is too open. If the page number is the only problem for a printed version, may be is worth set manually the start page in each article, for example:  `\setcounter{page}{16}` in the preamble.

If you need all in one pdf only, beside tools to merge pdf files, a LaTeX solution is compile each article without pages numbers. Just add this after `\maketitle`:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

And then use this main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{article1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{article2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{article3.pdf}
\end{document}
```

If you need a  more elaborated mixing, the answer depend of several questions:

- The articles are of the same document class?
- With a common preamble (same packages, same options)?
- You will use a only a general `\maketitle` and the title of each article could be changed by sections  or each `\maketitle` must be maintained ?
- Should be a table of contents showing the article titles and authors?

In the most complex cases, try first with the [combine](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine) document class, but take a look to another  alternatives of the [topic subdocs in CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/topic/subdocs) as `docmute` or `subdocs` if you only want use the contents of the articles as parts of a main document.